# Dynamically generating Spring Data Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on creating a library built on top of spring-data so that it would be able to dynamically generate Spring Data repositories. I was hoping to create a generic wrapper of this process that operates on the Spring Data abstraction.

This way depending on what dependency is added to the classpath example: `spring-data-jpa` or `spring-data-mongodb`  I would be able to generate repositories and inject them into my spring context.

I was having trouble finding good documentation on how to go about doing this.  Any ideas?

Comment: I mean spring boot does that for you.  Any reason for not using that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring provides a `@Conditional` annotation for controlling which beans/configurations are picked up depending on classpath ( similar with the `spring-boot` autoconfiguration ).

You could define two configuration classes which are picked up by spring based on your classpath.
For example:

1. Configuration for **JPA present on classpath** could look something like.

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=...)
   @Conditional(JpaClassPathCondition.class)
   public class JpaAutoConfiguration {

       static class JpaClassPathCondition implements Condition {

           @Override
           public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
               return ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.persistence.EntityManager", JpaAutoConfiguration.class.getClassLoader());
           }
        }
   }
   ```
2. Configuration for **MongoDB**:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableMongoRepositories(...)
   @Conditional(MongoClassPathCondition.class)
   public class MongoAutoConfiguration {

       static class MongoClassPathCondition implements Condition {

           @Override
           public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
               return !ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.persistence.EntityManager", MongoAutoConfiguration.class.getClassLoader()); )//or whatever classpath element fits you best

           }
        }
   }
   ```

All you need to do from this point forward is to use both configuration classes in your module and let spring do it's magic

Comment: Okay this is getting me most of the way. Awesome example!  The last part I don't fully understand is how to create a spring data repository and then inject it into the spring context.  Example:  If mongodb is on the classpath create N number of spring data repositories and inject them into the spring application context.  This problem means creating repositories that rely on the spring-data-mongodb dependency OR the JPA dependency depending on which is on the classpath

Comment: Repositories are created automatically if an `@Enable..Repository` annotation is found. All beans implementing `*Repository` interfaces( `CrudRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository` ) will be registered to the spring app context and available for autowiring.